# Xamarin Forms Essentials - event OnMainDisplayInfoChanged not fired on Android

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms

My Xamarin Forms Landscape to Portrait mode switching is working well on iOS.

In Android I never get the call to `OnMainDisplayInfoChanged` event.

```cs
public BaseVM()
{
    Connectivity.ConnectivityChanged += Connectivity_ConnectivityChanged;
    IsConnected = Connectivity.NetworkAccess != NetworkAccess.Internet;
    isConnected = CrossConnectivity.Current.IsConnected;
    DeviceDisplay.MainDisplayInfoChanged += OnMainDisplayInfoChanged;
    Title = isConnected ? "Students\r\n(webservice)" :
                                                        "Students\r\n(local cache)";
    IsPortraitMode = DeviceDisplay.MainDisplayInfo.Orientation == DisplayOrientation.Portrait;
    NetAccess = Connectivity.NetworkAccess.ToString();
}

private void OnMainDisplayInfoChanged(object sender, DisplayInfoChangedEventArgs e)
{
    IsPortraitMode = e.DisplayInfo.Orientation == DisplayOrientation.Portrait;
}
```

My MainActivity Decorator looks like this

```
 [Activity(Label = "TripCalculator", Icon = "@mipmap/icon",  Theme = "@style/MainTheme", MainLauncher = true,
        ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.ScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Orientation, ScreenOrientation = ScreenOrientation.Landscape)]
    public class MainActivity : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsAppCompatActivity
    {
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
```

Comment: if you put breakpoint its not hiting there?

Comment: Can you try to use OnSizeAllocated instead ? https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/180216/devicedisplay-maindisplayinfochanged-only-working-on-second-try

Comment: @Prateek Yes... It hits on iOS. Never hits on Droid.

Comment: @MarkWardell Version of XF and Essentials?

Comment: Please test it in Android Device, If you test it in the Android Emluator, it will have some strange issue. My Essential version is 1.3.1, Xamarin forms version is 4.5.0.356, it worked as normal.

Comment: That is the issue.... I do not have an Android Device. I have iOS device and no Droid. I need to get one at some point @Leon Lu Shouldn't it work on emulator? I can set a GitHub to show the bugs

Comment: Yes, you can open a thread in github to report this issue. Before you do that, could you try to set the value of `hw.gpu.mode` to host like this thread https://imgur.com/a/m4MW2NF